# Better performance searching SQL table with 170,000 rows

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have SQL table with 170,000 rows. Each row has column for string long approximately 600 characters.

I want to list all the rows, that contains searched keyword.

Using `LIKE '% keyword %'` takes about 1000ms. My app is build in Laravel using Eloquent.

Do you have any ideas what way would be the best for performane? I need to have options for searching case sensitive/insesitive, accent sensitive/insesitive, exact phrase or just multiple words in random order. So when I tried TNTSearch, the performance was excellent, but with not so much options.

Also, I tried to create index and Match Against function in my query, but there are also some limitations.

Answer (score 2):

Define `FULLTEXT` indexes on the columns which you want to be able to search to greatly increase search speed. Only works on MyISAM and InnoDB tables though.

Google it or have a look [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/introduction-to-mysql-full-text-search.aspx)

Comment: I already created index on the column, but when I search with wildcard before the keyword, it has to scan each row anyway...

Answer (score 2):

Like queries that begin with a wildcard cannot take advantage of indexes. Performance will continue to degrade as your table size grows.

I would recommend one of the following options for improving performance:

1. You can use [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scout)

> Laravel Scout provides a simple, driver based solution for adding full-text search to your Eloquent models.

Out of the box Scout supports [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/), but there are other drivers available as well, including TNTSearch

https://github.com/teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver

---

2. You can use a fulltext index to improve search performance.

Eloquent does not support fulltext search out of the box, but there are a few third party packages that add support.

Ex:

- https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence-base
- https://github.com/swisnl/laravel-fulltext

Comment: 1. Algolia is expensive for the project I work on; TNT Search has limited options when I want to search with/withouth accents 2. I'll try some of these packages, thanks

Comment: @sunergos there are elasticsearch and solr drivers as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using SOLR in combination with Solarium: https://solarium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/